# giving /var/www/site1 to www-data:www-data crashes all WP sites on server

Tags: linux, wordpress, permissions, ubuntu-16.04

-- See **Tl;dr** below for a short version --

On my ubuntu-16.04 droplet apache2 and php7 both use the user www-data. At some point all three installations of wordpress-4.7.2 seemingly without reason started asking for FTP credentials, indicating they don't have sufficient rights. Each wp instance has it's own mysql database.

I tried to solve this for /site1 with

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/site1/* -R
```

which shouldn't change anything as this is how the permissions were set already. For whatever reason this caused the browser to return a

```
HTTP ERROR 500
```

for the sites in /var/www/site1, /var/www/site2 and /var/www/site3 – nothing works anymore.

The only way I've found to get out of this is to restore the droplet. But each time I try to get the permissions right, I end up with all sites down again.

These are the current permission settings:

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Feb  3 XX:14 /var/
drwxrwxr-x 8 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  5 XX:27 /var/www/
drwxr-sr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  5 XX:13 /var/www/site1/
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 25 XX:51 /var/www/site2/
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 28 XX:06 /var/www/site3/
```

The sudo user is member of www-data:

```
user1@droplet:~$ members www-data
www-data user2 user1
```

A freshly installed Theme on /site1 caused dozens of PHP Fatal errors like this one:

```
[Sun Mar 05 19:24:04.003189 2017] [:error] [pid 5632] [client 31.10.138.238:50870] 
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_escape_string() 
in /var/www/site1/html/wp-content/themes/gloria/functions.php:60\nStack trace:\n#0 
/var/www/site1/html/wp-settings.php(425): include()\n#1 /var/www/bw/html/wp-config.php(89): 
require_once('/var/www/site1/htm...')\n#2 /var/www/bw/html/wp-load.php(37):
require_once('/var/www/site1/htm...')\n#3 /var/www/bw/html/wp-admin/admin.php(31): 
require_once('/var/www/site1/htm...')\n#4 /var/www/bw/html/wp-admin/themes.php(10): 
require_once('/var/www/site1/htm...')\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in
/var/www/site1/html/wp-content/themes/gloria/functions.php on line 60
```

After deleting the theme, /site1 went back online. I have no idea why. The first two times I ended up restoring the droplet because of

```
HTTP ERROR 500
```

this theme wasn't involved. Even though /site1 is back up, /site2 and /site3 remain stuck with

```
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Since the removal of the theme in /site1 the Apache Error Log doesn't have any suspicious entries:

```
[Sun Mar 05 19:56:35.456584 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1671] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sun Mar 05 19:56:35.662742 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1671] AH00163:     Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 05 19:56:35.662765 2017] [core:notice] [pid 1671] AH00094: Command     line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:** An instance of ActiveCollab in /var/www/site2/activecollab/ never stopped working during the whole issue. All connection and permission checks done by ActiveCollab for it's own files, folders and database are positive.

---

**Tl;dr:** WP1 asks for FTP, I say

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/site1/* -R
```

WP1, WP2 and WP3 tell the browser to

```
HTTP ERROR 500
```

while ActiveCollab in a subfolder of WP2 doesn't give a sh*t and keeps running.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

`sudo chmod -R 774 /var/www/yourwordpressfolder`

And then

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/yourwordpress`

Finally

`sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/yourwordpressfolder`

Comment: tried and didn't work. chances are it's not permissions related. Last night I've restored the droplet and all sites came back up. Without me changing anything today morning site2 and site3 were offline again while site1 keeps running.